# Concatenate Property of a object in Collection.

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Item
{
   public string id { get; set;}
   public string Color { get; set;}
}

public class Test
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public void ConCat
    {
        string a = ?
    }
}
```

I have above class structure and i want to concatenate colors in all the item within that collocation using LINQ. Any idea how to do this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
string a = string.Join(";", Items.Select(item => item.Color));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var res = yourList.Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
```

But, I recommend you to use `String.Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)`:

`var res = String.Join(";", yourList.Select(x => x.Name));`

**Additional Information**:

In such situations you can use either `Aggregate` or `String.Join()`. If we tests the execution times of the both query, we will see that the second is faster than the first one. But the reason is not `Aggregate()` function. The problem is we are concatenating strings in a loop. It will cause a lots of intermediate strings which will cause a bad performance. You can use `StringBuilder.Append`, if you want still to use Aggregate and increase the performance:

```
var res = yourList.Select(x => x.Name)
                   .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (current, next) => current.Append(next).Append(", "))
```

But, `String.Join()` uses a `StringBuilder` internally already and for that reason it will be the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You can return a comma-separated string of all colors. Use `String.Join` to concatenate strings with `,` separator as shown below.

```
public class Item
{
   public string id { get; set;}
   public string Color { get; set;}
}

public class Test
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public string AllColors()
    {
        return string.Join(",", Items.Select(i => i.Color));
    }
}
```